# Prevent Man in the Middle attack with AFNetworking

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, cocoa, ios4, afnetworking

I am using AFNetworking to send data over SSL. How do I prevent man-in-the-middle attacks? How can I be sure that I am receiving and sending the data to my server and not some other server?

Here is my code:

```
    @implementation API

@synthesize user;

#pragma mark - Singleton methods
/**
 * Singleton methods
 */
+(API*)sharedInstance
{
    static API *sharedInstance = nil;
    static dispatch_once_t oncePredicate;
    dispatch_once(&oncePredicate, ^{
        sharedInstance = [[self alloc] initWithBaseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:kAPIHost]];
    });

    return sharedInstance;
}

#pragma mark - init
//intialize the API class with the destination host name

-(API*)init
{
    //call super init
    self = [super init];

    if (self != nil) {
        //initialize the object
        user = nil;

        [self registerHTTPOperationClass:[AFJSONRequestOperation class]];

        [self setDefaultHeader:@"Accept" value:@"application/json"];
    }

    return self;
}

-(BOOL)isAuthorized
{
    return [[user objectForKey:@"id"] intValue]>0;
}



-(void)commandWithParams:(NSMutableDictionary*)params
                    path: (NSString *) pathstr
            onCompletion:(JSONResponseBlock)completionBlock
{
    NSMutableURLRequest *apiRequest =
    [self multipartFormRequestWithMethod:@"POST"
                                    path: pathstr
                              parameters: params
               constructingBodyWithBlock: ^(id <AFMultipartFormData>formData)
               {
                   //TODO: attach file if needed
               }];

    AFJSONRequestOperation* operation = [[AFJSONRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest: apiRequest];
    [operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
        //success!
        completionBlock(responseObject);
    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        //failure :(

        NSLog(@"%@", error);
        completionBlock([NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:[error localizedDescription] forKey:@"error"]);
    }];

    [operation start];

}
@end
```

and then I call:

```
[[API sharedInstance] commandWithParams: params
                                   path: @"user/registration"
                           onCompletion:^(NSDictionary *json)
 {
```

Comment: You can't really prevent the **man** of the attack. However, you could prevent the attack itself.

Comment: If you're using SSL with a certificate signed by a trusted authority then, AFAIK, this pretty much prevents a Man in the Middle attach. Take a look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man-in-the-middle_attack#Forensic_analysis_of_MITM_attacks

Answer (score 6):

I know it's 9 months late but I came across this SO question when researching my own solution to this question. In case others come across it too, here's what I understand the considerations / approaches are.

1. Using the approach you set out above leaves you open to MITM attacks. What the approach above does is use SSL for the connection and checks the certificate is valid. However it does not check whether the certificate is for your server. So the approach above will allow any valid certificate to be accepted as valid. So a program like Charles (http://www.charlesproxy.com) would enable you (or anyone) to see your https network traffic if they are able to act as a proxy between your app and your server.
2. To prevent against this, what you need is to switch on SSL Pinning (good article here: http://blog.lumberlabs.com/2012/04/why-app-developers-should-care-about.html). What this does is require the SSL connection to be from a server with a specific Certificate (which you embed in the app) or with a specific Public Key (which you also embed in the app).
3. Fortunately, with AFNetworking this is very easy to do. Simply set

   ```
   defaultSSLPinningMode = AFSSLPinningModeCertificate
   ```

   or

   ```
   defaultSSLPinningMode = AFSSLPinningModePublicKey
   ```

   on your AFHTTPClient. Then add the relevant certificate or public key to your app's bundle.
4. With the above approach, there is still the potential for someone to download the app and insert their own certificate or public key in the app's bundle and resign the app. I don't know the exact steps to do this but the issue is outlined here: https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/issues/1286.
5. To my mind, the best way to prevent against this is to encrypt the communications between the app and the server on top of using SSL Pinning. I'm currently looking at RNCryptor for this ( https://github.com/rnapier/RNCryptor)

I guess ultimately it comes down to what is the appropriate level of effort given what your app is doing and the data is it sharing.

Hope helpful, Charles.

Comment: How did you end up implementing step 5? Encrypting each parameter separately in your parameter dictionary that you're passing up via your AFHTTPClient?

Comment: @powerj1984 I ended up using RNCryptor and then actually implemented two different ways to send / receive data for my API. I can send / receive all the parameters individually (sending around 6 parameters). I can also send a single concatenated set of parameters. The reason for this was that I found that the RNCryptor algorithm on older Android phones took a while to run (a few seconds) so instead of running it 6 times the concatenated approach meant I run it once.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `kAPIHost` is an `https://` URL, you should be all good.

Really, all you can do is make your connections to known-good server addresses where the servers have trusted authority certificates. (provided by Thawte, VeriSign, etc.) It's sort of like saying "how can I be sure the post man isn't redirecting my mail?" You can't, but what you can do is use cryptography (i.e. cryptographic certificates, SSL, etc) to prevent the postman from reading the contents of your mail, and subsequently to authenticate the responses as being truly from the entity you expect.  This is what SSL exists to do (in the presence of a trusted certificate, etc.)

If you don't trust mainstream certificate providing entities, then you're pretty much left pre-sharing a secret and using shared-secret-based encryption.  In short, SSL is good enough for pretty much everyone else... hopefully it's good enough for you.